# what's wrong with declaring a variable inside if's condition?

Tags: c++, syntax, variable-declaration

Perhaps I am getting rusty (have been writing in Python recently).

Why does this not compile?

```
if ( (int i=f()) == 0)
```

without the `()` around the `int i=f()` I get another, much more reasonable error of `i` is not being boolean. But that's why I wanted the parentheses in the first place!

My guess would be that using the parentheses makes it into an expression, and that declaration statements are not allowed in an expression. Is it so? And if yes, is it one of the C++'s syntax quirks?

BTW, I was actually trying to do this:

```
if ( (Mymap::iterator it = m.find(name)) != m.end())
    return it->second;
```

Comment: What's wrong? Everything

Comment: @VJovic - I wander if you got your reputation score by such elaborate, helpful answers ;)

Comment: No, I would go negative ;) But seriously, any normal coding standards forbid such obscure code.

Comment: `for( int i = f(); i == 0;  i=1) {`  :-)

`for( Mymap::iterator it = m.find(name); it != m.end();  it = m.end()) {`  
... (only intended as a parlour trick)

Comment: c++ feature req: `[if|while]( var_decl_with_init ; expr ) statement`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can declare a variable in the `if` statement in C++ but it is restricted to be used with direct initialization and it needs to convert to a Boolean value:

```
if (int i = f()) { ... }
```

C++ doesn't have anything which could be described as "declaration expression", i.e. [sub-] expressions declaring a variable.

Actually, I just looked up the clause in the standard and both forms of initialization are supported according to 6.4 [stmt.select] paragraph 1:

```
...
condition:
   expression
   attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq declarator = initializer-clause
   attribute-specifier-seqopt decl-specifier-seq declarator braced-init-list
...
```

That is, it is also be possible to write:

```
if (int i{f()}) { ... }
```

Obviously, this only works in C++2011 because C++2003 doesn't have brace-initialization.

Comment: I don't think your last example is legal. You can only do `if (int i {f()}) { /*...*/ }` or `if (int i = f()) { /*...*/ }`. _braced-init-list_ must include braces. ( _braced-init-list_ is "{ _initializer-list_ ,OPT }" or "{ }").

Comment: @CharlesBailey: yes, you are right: I somehow mistook the "braced-init-list" to mean (...). I'll fix this.

Comment: thanks, sounds reasonable, and @Ilya's answer below gives some rationale

Comment: From your first sentence "but it is restricted to be used with direct initialization *and it needs to convert to a Boolean value*" -> can you please explain this in easy sentence? (I guess the value initialized works as Boolean value, right? but couldn't understand the restriction part also from your first line) , thanks

Answer (score 20):

There's a problem with scope.

Consider the following code:

```
if ((int a = foo1()) || (int b = foo2()))
{
    bar(b);
}
```

Is b declared inside the block? What if `foo1()` returns true?

Comment: forgot to mention that I don't think this is a scope issue as `()` AFAIK does not create scope. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @SoapBox but what if foo1 returns 1 and by short-circuit evaluation (which is guaranteed as far as I know) the assignation of `b` is skipped?

Comment: Exactly - You can't propose allowing variables to be declared in () unless you address the scope issue; variables in C++ have scope that begins when their declaration is 'executed', which may never occur in this situation.

Answer (score 5):

You can declare a variable in an if statement (or in for or while), but only in the outer parenthesis block and it needs to be able to be converted to bool.

Your guess is basically right, it's not allowed because

```
(int i = 42;)
```

is not a valid declaration with initialization.

You need one additional line,

```
Mymap::iterator it;
if ( (it = m.find(name)) != m.end())
    return it->second;
```

but then it's better to write

```
Mymap::iterator it = m.find(name);
if ( it != m.end() ) 
    return it->second;
```

You can put the `return` line after the `if`, if you really want this line back, at least for me this doesn't harm readability, but others might see that different.

If you really, really want to declare an iterator and use the it as bool in an `if` condition, you could do

```
if ( struct { int it; operator bool() { return it != m.end; } } s = { m.find(name) } )
    return s.it->second;
```

but I would consider this harmful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's true that you can't write

```
if ( (int i=f()) == 0)
```

but you can perfectly write

```
if ( int i=f())
```

So you can use the `&&` operator to perform both operations in one statement like

```
if ( int i=1 && (i=f()) == 0)
```

`i` should be initialized with any value other than 0, and it should be the first condition if your compiler applies left-to-right evaluation.

But unfortunately, that's not applicable in case of iterators as your second example asks.