# Declaring class variable inside an if statement

Tags: c++, class, variables, if-statement

c++ accepts:

```
if(int a=1)
{
    //...
}
```

For learning purposes, I have written a simple lock mechanism class:

```
class SimpleLock
{
public:
    class Token
    {
    public:
        friend class SimpleLock;
        Token(SimpleLock & lock) : lock(lock), locked(!lock.locked.exchange(true)) { }
        ~Token() { if(locked) lock.locked.store(false); }
        operator bool() const { return locked; }

    private:
        SimpleLock & lock;
        const bool locked;
    };

    SimpleLock() : locked(false) { }

private:
    std::atomic_bool locked;
};
```

allowing me to do:

```
SimpleLock::Token t(lock);

if(t) //Token has an operator bool() overload
{
    //...
}
```

Why doesn't the following compile?

```
if(SimpleLock::Token t(lock))
{
    //...
}
```

Compiler error:

> expected primary-expression before 't'

Online code link : http://goo.gl/Knrmw7

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen this asked before.

Comment: "*Why doesn't the following compile?*" Typically, the compiler tells you. Copy the message to your question.

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: Related: [what's wrong with declaring a variable inside if's condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961478/whats-wrong-with-declaring-a-variable-inside-ifs-condition)

Comment: @galinette I would probably have upvoted if it had a [mcve]. I do however not feel like writing code to find out if the question is even valid in the first place.

Comment: Does `if(SimpleLock::Token t{lock})` (note the braces) work?

Comment: @BaummitAugen : done!

Comment: @galinette Close enough, have the upvote. For education purposes: A [real mcve](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecb354450d25f1f7) including the error message.

Comment: @BaummitAugen now with the online compiler link...

Comment: @galinette As I said, the question was fine and the online compiler link does certainly not hurt, but what I tried to say is: a) Your example can be simplified significantly, the problem has nothing to do with the lock stuff b) I would like to be able to copy-paste and compile the mcve directly from the question and c) I would like to see the exact compiler error in the question. But again, your question is ok as is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't compile because that form of initialization is not allowed in an `if` condition. This is just down to the syntactic forms which the standard says are valid.

You can either use the copy-initialization form or a braced-init-list:

```
if(SimpleLock::Token t = SimpleLock::Token(lock))
{
    //...
}

if(SimpleLock::Token t{lock})
{
    //...
}
```

This is specified in `[stmt.select]/1` (N3337):

> condition:
>
> - expression
> - attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq declarator = initializer-clause
> - attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq declarator braced-init-list

Answer (score 3):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if

Syntax is `if ( condition )`

with condition is one of:

- expression which is contextually convertible to bool
- declaration of a single non-array variable with a brace-or-equals initializer.

We use the second bullet here, so

You have to use syntax with `=`:

```
if (SimpleLock::Token t = SimpleLock::Token(lock))
{
    //...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f48c275ce9008d7)

or construct your object with `{}` (instead of `()`)

```
if (SimpleLock::Token t{lock})
{
    //...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f38379578045353)

Comment: Likely because the copy operator returns something, not the constructor

Comment: Thanks, deleted my answer. This looks ok. BTW, in C++11, it looks like `if(SimpleLock::Token t{lock})` works. Cannot see why this is some vexing parse though...

Comment: This means I need a copy operator I suppose... My Token class is currently not copiable but I could implement a move assignment operator

Comment: @galinette: that use copy/move constructor, not assignment.

Comment: vsoftco : hey, the bracket syntax works!!! Thats really the dark side of C++... Could someone elaborate an answer about this?

Comment: I would say `t(lock)` is not accepted due to parsing (like the most-vexing parse).

Comment: @galinette Follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35411163/3093378. I don't think there should be any vexing parse here, although from the error it looks like there is, but don't know why.