# Why vexing parse in an if condition?

Tags: c++, c++11, most-vexing-parse

Consider the code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    Foo(int){}
    operator bool() const
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    if(Foo foo{42})
    {
        std::cout << "ok\n";
    }
}
```

It compiles fine under gcc5. However, if I replace the line `if(Foo foo{42})` with

```
if(Foo foo(42))
```

I get a compile-time error:

> error: expected primary-expression before 'foo'

What's going on here? There is no vexing parse imo, so why using braces work?

Comment: @Niall Yes, that's why I asked the question, before that answer appeared there. I should probably close it now as a dupe and link to that question.

Comment: I think a broader question is why is was not included to begin with. It may have been some compatibility issue, also not sure how it could be tied to the vexing parse; but I was somewhat surprised to was not allowed. Goes to show how little I ever initialize variables in the condition statement...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax for a *condition* does not include classic constructor invocation.

C++11 §6.4/1:

> *condition:*
>       *expression*
>       *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq declarator* `=` *initializer-clause*
>       *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq declarator braced-init-list*

This is used in `if`, `switch`, `while` and `do`. I was surprised to now discover that it's used in `switch`. I never thought of that as a condition.

Comment: With C++11, this looks like a small defect imo. Why would we be allowed to use `Foo foo{42}` but not `Foo foo(42)`? There are no parsing issues here.

Comment: Maybe to ease parsing? Having variable declarations in conditions is already a special case and parentheses are overloaded enough as it is.